# IIS How to allow a single file as browsable

Tags: iis, mime-type

I'm using IIS 7.5 and my goal to allow this one `json` file as browsable however I don't want any other `json` files to be accessible when navigating through the URL, therefore the typical IIS 404 page would appear.

I'm aware that you can allow all `json` files using the MIME Types feature per site or virtual directory, but I can't seem to figure out how to allow just the one file.

Answer (score 3):

In the web.config for your site, use something like this:

```
<location path="bar/foo.json">
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clear/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

directly under the `<configuration>` node.

Assuming you have not added a json mime type anywhere else, this should work. You specify this configuration for a specific url/file only.